# Why is my js script creating more then one option tag based on amount of characters in a said field rather then once?

Tags: javascript, html

I had a drop down menu that hides different options until they were filled in or not in a text input box, the problem was in safari that options can not be styled ( I had them hidden with display:none) until they are filled in.So I went with adding them to document with js when they are filled in the form. Now when I fill in say a phone number the script is adding the number of options based on the amount of characters and not just once how I want in the said field. I'm fairly new to js so any help would be appreciated.

The Javascript

```
function contactPhone() {
 var inputPhone = document.getElementById("inputPhone").value;
    if (inputPhone !== "") {
    var phone = document.createElement('option');
        phone.id = "contact_phone"
        phone.value ="phone"
        phone.innerHTML = 'Phone';

    document.getElementById("contact_option").appendChild(phone);
   }
}
```

The input html for the phone number

```
<li> 
    Phone:
    <input id="inputPhone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" oninput="contactPhone()">
</li>
```

Where the options should be added they add to the right spot but too many
I have one that always show which is in the html already when page loads

```
<div>
 <label>What is the best way to contact you?</label>
 <select id="contact_option" name="best_contact" onchange="jsContact()">
 <option value="email" id="contact_email">Email</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

The js that shows the options when the correct fields are filled in. Probably not needed for my answer but I figured id add it in just incase.

```
function jsContact(){
 var contact = document.getElementById("contact_option").value;
  if (contact == "mail" || contact == "email" || contact == "phone")  {
   document.getElementById("contact_submit").style.display = "block";
 }
  else {
   document.getElementById("contact_submit").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ryqjtwcv/

Comment: Simple... `oninput` fires for each key-stroke. You'll need to keep track of it it's been run or not

Comment: @Phil So what you recommend to remedy this?

Comment: onblur is an option as well if you only want it to fire when they leave the text field. The issue is that you're calling it every single character and if it's not blank you're appending an option.

Comment: Sweet it looks like onblur will work for me. Thanks man If one of you two wanna make this an answer ill gladly accept it. the only issue I can see if someone would click back in it again it would fire once again :(

Comment: You also should check if the option already exists to avoid more than one `phone` option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you could try to use onblur and as well you need to track the state of the options box.

In this case I just stuck a simple if statement in there to help you get the idea of where you could possibly check for the state of that options list

https://jsfiddle.net/qnj24hbn/10/

The Js

```
function contactPhone() {
  var contact_opts = document.getElementById("contact_option");
  // if it has more then 1 option in there don't do anything
  if (contact_opts.options.length === 1) {
    var inputPhone = document.getElementById("inputPhone").value;
    if (inputPhone !== "") {
      var phone = document.createElement('option');
      phone.id = "contact_phone"
      phone.value = "phone"
      phone.innerHTML = 'Phone';
      contact_opts.appendChild(phone);
    }
  }
}
```

The html

```
Phone:
<input id="inputPhone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" onchange="contactPhone()">
<div>
  <label>What is the best way to contact you?</label>
  <select id="contact_option" name="best_contact" onchange="jsContact()">
    <option value="email" id="contact_email">Email</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I like it it does what i need and if the user clicks back in there it wont fire again Sweet

Comment: Another option (instead of just checking to see if there is more then one option) would be iterating through the contact_opts Array and checking to make sure a specific value isn't in the list. If it answers your question don't forget to mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Yeah I know all about iterating and checking arrays for values in ruby but js not so much, but what you helped with is easy to understand so I can explain it a lot easier to my coworkers and let my bosses i know what it is doing